# Can Ubuntu tablet run on an A7 CPU?

Tags: cpu, tablet

I was wondering if Ubuntu tablet is companionable with A7 CPUs such as the ones that were released in the new kindle fire. I know they are compatible with A15 cpus.

Comment: the ubuntu *phone* runs on an A7 according to here http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=bq-ubuntu-phone-mediatek-blobs